# how to show notification in windows application using the c#

Tags: c#

I have used  notify icon as well as file system watcher but that doesn't give me the satisfactory output

**My requirement** : I am developing windows application where multiple users can insert data so whenever one user insert data in the database at that instant I want to notify others.  I am using SQL database

Comment: since you are using c#. I would advice you check https://www.asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using caching and when stuff gets invalidated other people are alerted.

An easy quick way for you is using a Database Table "InsertOperations" that is updated with every SQL INSERT. Use Stored Procedures and you can call a SQL function to insert the name of the InsertOperation into the dB Table.

When any user interacts with the dB check the Id of what is their latest InsertOperation, if it's lower than the MAX notify them of the lastest records in the InsertOperations db Table and update the variable in their copy of the app to the MAX Id.

Comment: thanks for reply can you please send me an attachment of small demo that will help me for better understanding

Comment: Why don't you post code? Would have been nice to begin with - we are not your research assistants. I think you need to code this up. I gave you the direction without source code like your question.